# Tkinter tkSimpleDialog.Dialog resize

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a class that derives from tkSimpleDialog.Dialog.

I have implemented the body(self, master) method, where I create some widgets (buttons, labels) and layout them using grid().

I set up the grid layout to stretch, but it never takes the full window. Furthermore, if I resize the window, the widgets will stay in place and not move.

Here's the initial layout:

[image: Initial layout]

And here's what happens when I resize the window:

[image: After resizing]

Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter
import tkSimpleDialog

class Test(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

    # ########################################
    def __init__(self, parent):

    tkSimpleDialog.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, "?")

    # ########################################
    def body(self, master):

        Tkinter.Label(master, text="Hello").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        Tkinter.Button(master, text="ONE").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        Tkinter.Button(master, text="TWO").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.resizable(height=True, width=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Test(Tkinter.Tk("test"))
```

The desired behavior is: buttons ONE and TWO will stretch to fill the window. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Dialog class. In the code where it packs the main part of the dialog it does this:

```
body.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
```

Note that it doesn't include an `expand` or `fill` attribute, so the body isn't going to grow to fill the extra room in its parent.

Comment: I confirm, changed that line to: body.pack(padx=5, pady=5, fill=BOTH, expand=True) and it's now working. The file on Windows is: <python dir>/Lib/lib-tk/tkSimpleDialog.py